# Validate Yahoo and Gmail Login

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am required to write a small webpage / utility for both Google and Yahoo to validate their email addresses. Suppose I give two textboxes, one for Yahoo and the other for Google. When the user provides the email addresses and hit the GO button I want to show if the provided emails actually exist and are valid or not. Plus, I would also like to show any publicly available information like Name, Date of Creation of Account or anything else that is available.

I have tried searching the net but was unable to find any helpful material. Hence asking the question here.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to implement oauth in your application. By doing so, the user can click on the button of a network and login there. The user will be redirected back to your application with some details (depending on the settings), in most cases you will get the email address and user name.

The simplest way to implement oauth I found was with Simple Authentication: https://github.com/SimpleAuthentication/SimpleAuthentication

An implementation I made: http://www.zonneprijzen.nl/Account after login go to: http://www.zonneprijzen.nl/User/Edit

Hopefully this solved your problem.